# Is this a situation where a constant is necessary in O(N) notation?

Tags: java, algorithm, arraylist, linked-list, big-o

In this [link](http://java67.blogspot.com/2012/12/difference-between-arraylist-vs-LinkedList-java.html) , the author says that `get(index)` is O(1) in Java ArrayList while it is O(n/2) in LinkedList, as it needs to traverse till that entry. The get operation in ArrayList taking constant time makes sense as ArrayList has access to all the indexes. However, I didn't understand O(n/2) for LinkedList. The way I was taught was that, when you use big oh notation, you should write it without the constant to make it easier to explain to someone else; that is, O(n) rather than O(2n). Isn't O(n) also a bound for the worst case running time? That way it makes more sense to me to use O(n) because the element you are searching for could be at the very end. Does anyone know why the author included the n/2?

Comment: Yes, O(n/2) is exactly the same thing as O(n). Don't believe everything you read on the Internet. ;)

Comment: The article was well written though. I think he knows that since he used O(n) in another section. Just curious as to why he included the n/2 rather than n. He must have had a reason for doing so

Comment: As a comment: when you want to say about n/2 elements but don't want to fuss with lower order terms, it's very frequent to abuse notation and write things like n/2 + O(1) elements inspected or even n/2 + o(n).

Comment: @DavidEisenstat - I'm not so sure about that being an abuse of the same kind as O(n/2). The [Wikipedia article on big-O notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation), among others, explains: _"g(x) = h(x) + O(f(x))" expresses the same as "g(x) - h(x) ∈ O(f(x))"_. With that extension of notation (which is very common), n/2 + O(1) denotes "some function g(n) such that g(n) - n/2 ∈ O(1)," which should satisfy the most stringent notation police.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right that O(n/2) is exactly the same thing as O(n). The blog post author was probably trying to communicate something about how a `LinkedList` needs to, on average, traverse n/2 elements to get to any particular (randomly selected) index. But this is an abuse of big-O notation.

To be fair to the author, he or she seems perfectly aware that O(n) = O(n/2):

> In order to remove an element from a particular index ... `ArrayList` performs a copy operation which makes it close to O(n) while `LinkedList` needs to traverse to that point which **also** makes it O(n/2)

By using "also", the poster seems to be acknowledging this.